# How to view cached pages in Chrome cache?

Tags: file, google-chrome, caching

A website I like has taken itself offline, and there is no cached version on google or archive.org. I have not cleared my cache; could it possibly be stored in the browser?

I am using a Chromebook; have tried extensions but they seem to be fixated on searching google (just to reiterate: this is finding a cached page on Chrome, NOT online). Appreciate this has probably been answered already but can't find a clear answer as Chrome has changed a lot over the years.

Thank you for any help

Using developer in Chrome, searching online, using extensions